# why is my if statement showing to be false? code not not quitting when a==0. the time is supposed to be in min/sec

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

i am having trouble figuring out why my timer is not reaching zero when i run it. I am trying to get the window to close when a=0 but a keeping decreasing to negative digits why please? This is my codes

```
def close_timer(self):
    global a
    a = float(a - 0.1)
    self.labeltext.set(str(("%.1f" % (a))))
    a = float(a)
    print a
    print (a == 0)
    if a == 0:
        self.canvas.after(100)
        self.root.destroy()
    self.root.after(100,self.close_timer)
```

Comment: By the way, the line `a = float(a)` is unnecessary - `a` already is a `float`. Also, you probably don't want to use global variables, especially in a class.

Comment: thanks alot, y is it considered bad using a global variable in a class?

Comment: Well, as soon as you have more than one instance of the class, they would all share the same global state, which usually isn't what you want. If you do `self.a = 0` in your class' initialization routine, you create an instance variable that will remain in your object and can be accessed from all its methods.

Comment: sorry i am really new at this programming stuff but do u mean that if a=50 and instead of using global a, I should instead equate self.a = 50 instead? could u please give me an example using my code above that would really help please and thanks :)

Comment: Take a look at http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#classes, that should get you started.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Floating point number math [is generally inaccurate](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) - you can't represent a decimal `0.1` in binary floating points exactly, therefore you'll never reach `0`:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> while a > 0:
...     a = a - 0.1
...     print(repr(a))
...
0.9
0.8
0.7000000000000001
0.6000000000000001
0.5000000000000001
0.40000000000000013
0.30000000000000016
0.20000000000000015
0.10000000000000014
1.3877787807814457e-16
-0.09999999999999987
```

Use `if abs(a) < 0.000001:` or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

It's always dangerous to compare floats with fixed values unless you know and mitigate the consequences.

Most likely, your value is getting down to something like:

```
0.099999923354
```

as imprecision is gradually injected into your value every time you subtract `0.1` (which is not directly representable in IEEE754).

Then, when you subtract the final `0.1`, you get something like:

```
-0.00000005345
```

which is *not* equal to zero.

Quickest fix is to probably change your zero check to be:

```
if a <= 0:
```

so that small errors are irrelevant, other than possibly taking an extra cycle (probably a tenth of a second) if it reaches `0.0000001` where it should be zero, for example.

If you want to ensure you don't take that extra cycle and you're confident that the gradually introduced error won't be too large, just change it to:

```
if a <= 0.0003:
```

or something similar.

Comment: `if a <= 0` will not work correctly. Since `0.1` is represented as slightly less than actual `0.1` in binary, there will be a value for `a` that should be `0` (triggering the `if`) but will actually be around `1e-16` and therefore not triggering the `if`.

Comment: @Tim, see my final paragraphs. Yes, it may delay an extra cycle but that's _probably_ not going to matter. If it does, then simply use a comparison with a delta, something like `if (a < 0.02)`.

Comment: OK, I don't know what tkinter's `canvas.after()` does, so if that operation doesn't affect anything, then of course it doesn't matter. (I wrote my comment before your edit.)

Comment: @TimPietzcker: 0.1 as a double is slightly more than 1/10, due to rounding of 0x9 up to 0xA in the last nibble of the mantissa (i.e.  0.1999999999999A in hexadecimal). However, `1.0 - 0.1` is slightly bigger than 9/10 because bits are lost to align the two doubles on the binary point.